# Surround a text/word with braces using vscodevim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Is there is any shortcut to wrap in braces or quotes selected text/word in vscodevim plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vscodevim replicates the functionality of the surround-vim plugin, which means it provides a couple of operators to deal with surrounding.

In your case, `ys` should help you.
On a visual selection, `ys"` will add quotes.

[More on this here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vim-surround)

Comment: Did nit work for me

Comment: didn't work for me either

Comment: Adding quotes with a visual selection still seems to not work, but it's very possible I'm doing it wrong. What did work for me is 1) individual words with `ysw"`, 2) multiple words with `ys3w"`, 3) with your cursor inside a word with `ysaw"`, and 4) things like surrounding until the end of the line with `ys$"`.

Comment: I noticed it works with VISUAL selection but not with VISUAL BLOCK selection.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the extension in VS Code works for me; the syntax is:

**y s <motion> <desired>**

So one example would be:

**ysw"**

- w -> motion to define from your cursor till the end of that word
- " -> What should surround the word

Note that motion will define what is surrounded. Therefore you can write

**ysiw"**

- iw -> surrounding the word not dependent on your cursor

Comment: `ysiw` worked perfectly, thanks!